# Accessing Instance Variable on Another Method Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to print the obj.age, obj.name and obj.gender on my printStuff method but I can't seem to access it. What's the right way to access it?

Here's my code:

```
public class myLove {
   int age;
   String name;
   char gender = 'M';
   static char status;
   static String address;
   
   public static void main(String args[]){
      myLove.address = "Tiptop ambuclao";
      myLove.status =  'S';
      
      myLove obj = new myLove();
      obj.age = 17;
      obj.name = "John Doe";
      obj.gender = 'M';
   }
   
   public void printStuff(){
       System.out.println("Name: "+name);

}
```

}

Comment: How can you access *what* exactly from another method? It's unclear to me what you're trying to achieve that your current code doesn't do. (As an aside, I'd strongly encourage you to use private fields and follow Java naming conventions.)

Comment: I'm trying to print the variables from the main method on my printStuff method. Sorry I wasn't clear

Comment: Adding to Jon Skeet's advice, don't use static attributes either. Your code will work if you add `obj.printStuff()` to the main method.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to call `printStuff` from the `main` method you can simply do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  MyLove myLove = new MyLove();

  // set some data here

  myLove.printStuff();
}
```

### Old Answer:

Since your `printStuff` method is public, you can access it from any other class:

```java
public class OtherClass {
  
  public static void printMyLove(MyLove myLove) {
    myLove.printStuff();
  }

}
```

This can be simply called from your main method like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  MyLove myLove = new MyLove();

  // set some data here

  OtherClass.printMyLove(myLove);
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I wasn't clear. I wanted to print the variable's values from my main class on my printStuff class